# What would cause my desktop system fans to run at 100% during sleep?

Tags: sleep, windows-11, fan

I have a Dell XPS 8940, running Windows 11.  Everything is up to date regarding drivers, etc.  Whenever my computer goes into sleep mode, or I manually activate sleep, the cooling fans for the processor kick on at 100% power.  I have been searching for answers, but most of the suggestions from google are about laptops, or how to work with fans to make them quiet... Not actually solving the underlying issue (the fans should basically stop).  As soon as I move the mouse, they stop and everything goes back to normal when it wakes up.

powercfg /sleepstudy is inconclusive.  I see No CS Phase PDC Phase 99% but I have no idea what that means.  I can share the sleep study if needed.

I don't have any oddball TSR programs, and I wouldn't expect them to do much during sleep anyway.

It used to work properly.  I'm a c# developer, but I'm not much of a hardware guy.  Has anyone seen this before?  I would like to let my PC sleep, but i've been just disabling it for the time being.

Edit: FWIW I hear something click that sounds like a relay when the fans kick on and off.

Here is a video of it doing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTDFG3UY358

Comment: It cannot possibly be sleeping properly - update BIOS, and Power Drivers. Set power management to default and test.

Comment: I would also enter bios and see what the settings are there.